# right-continuity of filtration

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes

For a natural filtration of a stochastic process (possibaly multi-dimensional) to be right-continuous, what conditions should the process satisfy? Any references?

Comment: While not an exact duplicate, does this answer your question? http://mathoverflow.net/questions/46957/right-continuity-of-natural-filtrations